# Time interval as the independent variable

Tags: regression, self-study

[image: time interval as the independent variable for linear regression]

How do I find the $a$ and $b$ in $Y=a+bX$? The way I have been doing it so far are by the formulas with tons of $\Sigma(X)$ and $\Sigma(Y)$

Comment: It's not clear what your question is, because you say you have been doing regression. This problem presents several difficulties, such as reporting data in two-year intervals (which conflicts with the statement that these are "annual installations") and the vague and confusing note at the end.  Where exactly are you looking for help? With understanding sigma notation? Performing a linear regression? Making sense of this (terrible) homework question?

Comment: whuber, I'm looking for help with linear regression. I'm not sure how to deal with an interval as the independent variable.

Comment: mike, thanks for answering! but umm I am at an incredibly basic level, doing stuff by hand, no comp/calc/not sure.

Comment: This IS a terrible question.

Comment: For the time variable, the usual thing is to take the value at the center of the interval (i.e. 2002, 2004, 2006) as your x-value. If you're stuck doing these by hand, you're pretty much going to deal with calculations involving lots of $\sum x_i$'s and so on. (But if you can access the internet - and it seems you can, there are some ways you may be able to use R, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking how to write this as a linear regression equation and then finding the coefficients of the fit. Consider the following example written in R:

```
### Create a data frame to hold year (independent variable) and number of computers (dependent variable)
df <- data.frame(year = c(1,2,3,4,5),  ## Just turn the year into a value
                 computers = c(139,144,150,154,158))
plot(df)
linear.model <- lm(computers ~ year, data = df)
abline(linear.model)
summary(linear.model)
```

which yields

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 134.6000     0.7659  175.73 4.06e-07 ***
year          4.8000     0.2309   20.79 0.000244 ***
```

Therefore, your final model for y = m*x + b is

```
Number of computers = 4.8*year + 134.6
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you really want to calculate this by hand there is a ton of information about this on the web, for instance just look at (http://sciencefair.math.iit.edu/analysis/linereg/hand/) or (http://www.stat.rutgers.edu/home/buyske/401/RegHand.html). For the year just simply turn them into 1,2,3,.. or take the middle year for each interval such as 2002,2004,.. If you take the coefficients that I gave you and plot them with your data you will find a very good fit.